# OAuth 2.0 token generation service in Outsystems

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, access-token, outsystems

I'm working in a demo where I need to consume a REST API that needs an access token. Currently I'm generating this token with Postman and using it parametrically but I need to make automatic. I already have everything I need but the service to generate this token.

If someone can help me, I would be very thankful.

I tried to generate the token with Postman and use it in a variable, it works, but I need to make ir automatic.